# Changing page layouts with workflow rules does not work

Tags: workflow, page-layout, record-type

once a campaign approval status has changed to "approved", the campaign pagelayout is supposed to change (so that the "submit for Apporval" button is hidden).

I tried to solve this with a workflow rule, record types and different pagelayouts, but it does not work. In detail I did the following:

- I created 2 page layouts: 1.: new campaign / 2.: approved campaign
- I created a workflow rule:

  - evaluate when: created, and every time it’s edited
  - formula: ISPICKVAL( Approval_Status__c , "approved")
    syntax is checked and fine
- I created 2 record types: 1.: new campaign / 2. approved campaign
- I set the record type "new campaign" as default
- I assigned the pagelayouts to the record types

Now, when a campaign is submitted and approved, the approval process (field update) changes the approval status to "approved". This works fine. I now expected the record type (and with it the pagelayout) to change, so that the "submit for Approval button" is no longer available. But it doesn´t. The record type remains "new campaign" and the "submit for approval" button is still there.
I am a little frustrated and hope anyone can help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing is right; assuming that you assigned a field update to the workflow rule to update the record type. The problem here could be as simple as the workflow rule not being activated. You could also look at the field update you have on the approval process. There is a checkbox there that when checked will reevaluate workflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a second field update too on the same workflow. This field update should be on "Record Type" field to update it to second value. Once record type changes, the layout will also get updated.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!
Ruchika

Answer (score 0):

From your campaign approval process itself add one more field update in the approval section to modify the record types then it will work as per your page layout assignment with respective record type & profiles.